# some td borders don't show in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, border

[image]

Borders of td in some top rows disappear, but the rest bottom rows are just fine. When I scroll from bottom to top, the borders show at first, but will suddenly disappear.

The problem doesn't occur in safari and chrome.

When I comment 'border-collapse:collapse', the problem also doesn't occur.

Another table with same style but fewer columns is alright.

Has anyone ever met the problem too? And how can I resolve it?

Thx.

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
 }
 
 th, td{
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
  padding: 18px 0 18px 12px;
  text-align: left;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Care to provide the code?

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue on Firefox. The problem might be with some other properties.